# Solspace User, unable to reset password

Tags: ee1, solspace-user

I'm working on an EE 1.6.8 site with SolSpace User 3.0.1 .  The password reset form does not seem to be working.  When entering the new password in the Confirm New Password box, a message comes up straight away "Please enter the same value again".  Both passwords are the same.  Thanks.

```
{exp:user:edit return="account/index"}

<h1>Change Password</h1>

<p><label for="password">New Password</label> <input type="password" name="password" class="pass" /></p>
<p><label for="password_confirm">Confirm New Password</label> <input type="password" name="password_confirm" /></p>
<p><label for="current_password">Current Password </label><input type="password" name="current_password" /></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Update" /></p>

{/exp:user:edit}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance your code looks fine to me.

If you look at [the change log for User](http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/change_log/) module you'll see many changes relating to passwords.

Some examples:

- Fixed a bug where edit_profile was xss cleaning password_confirm and
  current_password, unintentionally disallowing ampersands and other
  special characters in passwords.
- Fixed a bug where the Register and Edit tags were messing up
  passwords containing ampersands.
- Fixed a bug where ampersands in passwords would cause issues from
  User

Perhaps you should update and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I'm working with an EE 1 site, is there anyway to get hold of EE 1 versions of the add on?  They don't seem to be available anywhere.  I think the last version before support for EE 1 was dropped was 3.3.10, is this available to download?

Comment: I'd recommend you reach out to the fine folks at Solspace.